# ReadFile COM full batch

Tags: c, winapi, serial-port, readfile, createfile

I'm using winapi (in C) to read a batch from a comport using the following creating the port:

```
hSerial= CreateFile(COM5, 
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
0,
NULL,
OPEN_EXISTING, 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL |FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 
NULL);
```

and then reading a batch into Data which is lengthIn long :

```
ReadFile(hSerial,Data,lengthIn,lengthOut,NULL)
```

lengthOut represents the amount of data actually read.

I need to make sure I actually read lengthIn bytes at each iteration and not less, how do I do that? How do I make sure lengthIn=lengthOut each time?

I think it has something to do with the attribute while creating the port (like the FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING), but I'm not sure which one and how.

Comment: You could keep reading until you have all the data. Another way of processing when you can recieve arbitrary chunks of data is just to receive all into a buffer then process that as needed.

Comment: I thought about it Deanna, but thought there must me some automatic way, like @Jonathan Potter suggested. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the timeouts on the comm port handle large enough, then `ReadFile` will effectively not return until the number of bytes you've specified has been read (or an error has occurred).

See the docs on the `COMMTIMEOUTS` structure (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363190(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! Do you know if this means that this will be also the delay? Meaning if I set a timeout of 10mSec and get all the needed data in 3 mSec will it wait the other 7?

Comment: No, the call will return as soon as the specified number of bytes is read (or the delay expires, or another error occurs). For example, if the number of bytes you ask for is already in the comm buffer then the call will return immediately.